# How large will my buddy's eyes appear underwater while wearing goggles?

Tags: optics, refraction, vision

My buddy and I are underwater scuba diving.
We are both wearing diving masks.

I know an object in the water will appear 1.33 times larger.

But how large will my buddy's eyes appear inside of his dive mask.

Comment: His eyes are in air. So are yours.

Comment: so will they look the same?